# Excel VBA Auto Filter Error

Tags: excel, vba

I've written code to compare the data included in 2 huge Excel files and while running the comparison code I encounter a "Run time error '91' - Object Variable or With block variable not set". Anyone know what my error is? Please see picture of code below:

Run Time Error 91:

[image]

Comment: Next time, please copy/paste the code in here, instead of a picture^^ It makes it easier to dissect.

Comment: Ok thanks, will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Range("A1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveWorkbook.WorkSheets("Old Data").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
```

`Selection.AutoFilter` with no parameters is simply a toggle. [Read More on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx)

The reason you are getting an error is because you are not clearing the filter before you run your macro.  Since you are not clearing it, this `.AutoFilter` is actually turning filter off. If there is no `AutoFilter`, there are no `Sort.SortFields` to `.Clear`,

Solution: Ensure the sheet's `AutoFilterMode` is turned off before you start calling all your `.AutoFilter` toggles.

```
ActiveWorkbook.WorkSheets("Old Data").AutoFilterMode = False
Range("A1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveWorkbook.WorkSheets("Old Data").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
```

Comment: Awesome, this makes sense now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you **don't need** `AutoFilter` at all in order to sort a range, `AutoFilter` is meant for human interaction with a drop-down GUI,

### Method #1 - Sort range directly

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Old Data").Columns("AG").Sort key1:=Range("AG1:AG"), order1:=xlDescending, header:=xlYes
```

[see this to learn how to sort a Range directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.sort)

### Method #2 - Sort range using SortFields

if you sort using SortFields, then you can clear the sort later on

```
' set the fields to sort by
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Old Data").SortFields.Add Key:=Range("AG1:AG"), Order:=xlDescending

' Perform the actual sort
ActiveWorksheet.SortFields.Sort Header:=xlGuess
```

[see this to learn how to sort using SortFields](https://see%20this%20to%20learn%20how%20to%20sort%20a%20Range%20using%20SortFields)

### Method #2.1 - Clear range (that was created using SortFields)

```
' Clear the current sort
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Old Data").SortFields.Clear
```

[see this to learn how to clear a sort that was created using SortFields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sortfields.clear)

The full code should look something like this:

```
' Clear the current sort
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Old Data").SortFields.Clear

' set the fields to sort by
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Old Data").SortFields.Add Key:=Range("AG1:AG"), Order:=xlDescending

' Perform the actual sort
ActiveWorksheet.SortFields.Sort Header:=xlGuess
```